# GetElementById('div'+i) increment

Tags: javascript

I have tried searhing through the site but I can't find what I'm looking for..

I have created a div id with increment and I wanted to select that div tag since I'm trying to set the width via javascript GetElementById since the code I'm running wouldn't work if you use GetElementsByClass

Here's what im working on

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("mycontent");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
list[i].setAttribute("id", "custom-id-" + i);
}
var widthx = document.getElementById('testx').offsetWidth;
document.getElementById('div-2').style.width = widthx + 'px';
document.getElementById('div-3').style.width = widthx + 'px';
document.getElementById('custom-id-'+i).style.width = widthx + 'px';
document.getElementsByClass('mycontent').style.width = widthx + 'px';
```

these two works

```
document.getElementById('div-2').style.width = widthx + 'px';
document.getElementById('div-3').style.width = widthx + 'px';
```

however this is what I needed to work

```
document.getElementById('custom-id-'+i).style.width = widthx + 'px';
document.getElementsByClass('mycontent').style.width = widthx + 'px';
```

any ideas how can I get this to run? here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/naldjb/e92au/)

thnks in advance guys

Comment: `i` is only `list.length` at that point -- is that intended?

Comment: What is `getElementsByClass`? Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: Where did you define *getElemensByClass*? There is a [*getElementsByClassName*](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname), but that isn't supported by all browsers in use.

Comment: `('custom-id-'+i)` should be inside the loop ! right ?

Comment: Too much wrong.  Will not teach what the web provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `i` out of scope.

In other words, you can't reference the variable `i` from outside the `for` loop because you don't have access to it from there, so you need to move everything inside of the loop.

Also, `getElementsByClass()` is not a function. You're looking for [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName).

If you use *that* for your last line, it works.

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("mycontent");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].setAttribute("id", "custom-id-" + i);
    var widthx = document.getElementById('testx').offsetWidth;

    document.getElementById('div-2').style.width = widthx + 'px';
    document.getElementById('div-3').style.width = widthx + 'px';
    document.getElementById('custom-id-' + i).style.width = widthx + 'px';
    document.getElementsByClassName('mycontent')[i].style.width = widthx + 'px';
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/e92au/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Should be inside loop:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("mycontent");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
list[i].setAttribute("id", "custom-id-" + i);
list[i].id = 'custom-id-' + i; list[i].style.width = widthx + 'px';
}
```

Comment: Or `list[i].id = 'custom-id-' + i; list[i].style.width = widthx + 'px';` is a lot less to type an much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('custom-id-'+i).style.width = widthx + 'px';
```

The above statement fails, current value of `i` is `2`, there is no `div` with `id` `custom-id-2` in the page.

```
document.getElementsByClass('mycontent').style.width = widthx + 'px';
```

The above statement should be

```
document.getElementsByClassName('mycontent');
```

Then again, `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an `array`; which does not have `style` attribute.

You can assign the value of `document.getElementsByClassName('mycontent');` to a variable and `iterate` over it to perform the desired action.